# How can we pull the fbid for posts made by fans of a community page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page, facebook-insights

We are working to compile information about posts on a community page. We are currently able to pull the fbid from posts that are made by admins of the page and we would also like to pull the fbid for posts made by fans of the community.

For example, if a fan that makes a post such as, "I love this product" on the wall of a product we are currently unable to reliably access the information about this post.

The specific difference that we have noticed is that for most links, the fbid is presented in the xxxxxxxxxxxxxx format, while a post on the feed from a fan will be represented as xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx. Is there a reliable way to derive this information when given a link that points directly to this post?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking here.

You can get all the posts made by others on a fan page easily in FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = $page_id 
  AND filter_key = 'others'
```

If you know the `post_id`, this query will tell you who posted it:

```
SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE post_id = $post_id
```